# std::vector push_back crashing

Tags: c++

Hello im making a manager

Color class inside Color.h -included before Manager.h

`Manager.h

```
class ColorEntry
{
private:
    const char* m_pszName;
    Color m_colColor;

public:
    inline const char* GetName(void) const { return m_pszName; }
    inline void SetName(const char* pszName) { m_pszName = pszName; }
    inline Color GetColor(void) { return m_colColor; }
    inline void SetColor(Color colNew) { m_colColor = colNew; }
};

class CColorManager
{
private:
    std::vector<ColorEntry*> m_vecColors;
public:
    void Initialize(void);
    --etc
}
```

Manager.cpp

```
void CColorManager::Initialize(void)
{
    AddColor("GUI_Outline", Color(0, 128, 255));
}

void CColorManager::AddColor(char* pszName, Color col)
{
    ColorEntry NewCvar;
    NewCvar.SetName(pszName);
    NewCvar.SetColor(col);
    m_vecColors.push_back(&NewCvar); -- crash here
}`
```

help i tried many ways none work also i have another way that does this but with no Color and it works so is it the color thats messing it up?

color is a class with 4 bytes

Comment: Please make a small but *compilable* example to see the problem.

Comment: Btw., `Color class inside Color.h -included before Manager.h` sounds like the order of your includes is important ... you can include Color.h (additionally) in Manager.h too so that the order makes no difference anymore.

Comment: Just don't make containers of naked pointers. All of the benefits of containers are lost when they operate on objects that don't follow normal value semantics.

Answer (score 1):

This line

> m_vecColors.push_back(&NewCvar); -- crash here

adds pointer of local variable, which is no longer valid after AddColor finished. You need to add here pointer returned from calling `new` like:

```
ColorEntry* pNewCvar = new ColorEntry();
 // ...
m_vecColors.push_back(pNewCvar);
```

but then you need to manage its lifetime, so its better to put this pointer into std::shared_ptr.

Comment: i see, would doing this and then safely removing it using delete[] work?

Comment: @jacobharris using `delete`, `delete[]` is for arrays. I would suggest using: `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<ColorEntry>> m_vecColors;`.

Comment: another thing is that `AddColor(char* pszName, Color col)` should be `AddColor(const char* pszName, Color col)`

Comment: still nothing, crashes the same way

Comment: Hard to tell, I dont see other reason why it crashes from code example you have provided. Actually adding pointer, even invalid, to vector should not crash